# Callback Javascript function through Json return from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

Is it Possible ? If yes how to perform, if No how to do ?

```
<?php 
 //-----
  function save(){
    //some stuff...
     return json_encode(['callback' => 'refreshList('.$id.')']);
   }
?>
<script text="javascript">
  $.ajax({ 
   //--Ajax....
        success: function (response) {              
             if (response.callback)
               {                    
                  callback = response.callback;
                  callback($param); //<--- Here my Issue, Execute callback from PHP script with parameter ...
               }
        }
     });     
</script>
```

How to achieve this to make it run

Comment: You are better off leaving this entirely in JS, instead of the server sending JS what to run. It makes very little sense to do that - you are putting frontend logic in the backend which means  they are now coupled very tightly.

Comment: @VLAZ what snippet do you propose

Comment: Instead of sending what *function* to call with what *argument*, you don't do that. At best, send the ID if you don't have it already, although I assume you do. Simply call `refreshList(id)` in JS and don't concern PHP with that logic. Imagine you want to rename the function to `refreshTable` or to add a second argument  - you'd only need to make changes to the front end, not both the frontend and the backend.

Comment: @VLAZ, i entirely agree with your proposition but in this case the callback _MUST_ be defined into the backend, because it could have another function to call back.  so the function name to callback is **parameterizable**. Imagine i want to callback  _openBox_  **instead of** _refreshList_ ??? how to say that it's openBox a want to run ??

Comment: What are you basing this decision on? Surely it's frontend logic whether you want to refresh a list or open a box - it's all stuff that the frontend would do.

Comment: @VLAZ When the 'php'  save($form, $callback ) function is called, the user can define what function can be called as callback ...if the user wants a refreshLIst after saving or openDialog or wipeField or any function else .....etc

Comment: In that case, you'd have the server send a UI a hint and the UI would take that and use whatever is appropriate. This breaks the tight coupling and you are still left with the frontend in charge of what happens. Another option is to send config to the page on initialisation - the config would still contain a hint for the post-save action but then the server doesn't even care about sending hints every time you interacts with it - it sends you the data you configured and is thus oblivious to what a post-save actions *is* as a whole.

Comment: Ps: The javascript callbacks functions are in extern .js file. it was just a snippet to expose my issue...

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant - an external JS file still belongs to the UI. You would have the frontend decide what to call, not the backend. Changing that file means multiple changes that are simply unneeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call all global functions like this `window["functionName"](arguments);`
So you have to pass 2 arguments from php

```
{
  "callback" => 'myFunction', 
  "args" => [
     1, 2, 3
  ],
}
```

And in js you can run

`window[data.callback](...data.args)`